# React unit test with enzyme, test onBlur functionality

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component with functionality which validates input element onblur and adds error class if validation fails:

```
TableRows = (props )=>(
 return  <input class="inputElement" onBlur="this.validate()" />
)
```

validate function is as follows:

```
validate = async ({ target }: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        try {
            const element = target;
            this.setState({ loading: true });
            const { value } = target;
            const match = value.match(/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/g);
            if (!match || match.length === 0) {
                element.className += ' inputError';
            } else {
                element.className = target.className.replace(' inputError', '');
            }

            const { data: updatedValues } = await sendforSaving({inputValue: value});
            this.setState({ newValues: data });
        } finally {
            this.setState({ loading: false });
        }
    };
```

I am trying to write a unit test with enzyme as follows:

```
it('should add error class on invalid input onblur', () => {
        const mockVal4Test = {
            localCurrency: 'USD',
            value: '20.02.1',
        } as any;
        component = shallow(
            <TableRows {...defaultProps} initialValues={mockVal4Test} currencyType={CurrencyType.LOCAL} />
        );
        const myInput = component.find('.inputElement');
        myInput.simulate('blur');
        expect(saleTarget.hasClass('inputError')).toBe(true);
    });
```

I get the myInput element but after simulating blur I am expecting the 'validate' function to be called and error class "inputError" to be added to the element.

Answer (score 0):

I used a mock event for blur event to pass to simulate. And later the same mock event is used to check the changes, as the blur event changes the passed event object. Here is my solution.

```
it('should add error class on invalid input for StoreTarget input on blur', () => {
        component = shallow(
        <TableRows {...defaultProps} initialValues={mockVal4Test} currencyType={CurrencyType.LOCAL} />
    )
        const mockedEvent = { 
            target: { 
                value: '1.2.1.2', 
                className:'inputClass'
            }
        } as any;
        const myInput = component.find('. inputElement');
        myInput.simulate('blur',  mockedEvent );
        expect(mockedEvent.target.className.includes('inputError')).toBe(true);
    });
```